# What happens when we travel into the past?

Tags: time-travel

**I read that when we travel into the past past we actually travel to a parallel universe.
What is the reason?
Who said that?**

Comment: Welcome to wb.se. Please check with the Help Center (http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) about the questions handled here.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. I am sorry but I have to put a "close" vote on your question because it is not at all about building a world. Further more, the only direction is which we can do time travel is **forward**, and doing so is never instantaneous. The only thing we can affect is the rate at which we travel forward in time. Please look at the link provided by @AlexandervonWernherr for information on how to post a good question on WB SE.

Comment: Yes, I too saw this in the news recently. [Here is a link to the recent announcement.](http://bit.ly/2glkV1m)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of travelling into a parallel universe when travelling into the past. But I think you may be referring to a tree like structure of time.

Every action you take, or don't take creates an instant offspring of your current universe.

So if you travel back in time, e.g. 20 minutes back and decide not to write this post, but rather check the worldbuilding wiki and help center, you'd split your universe into to separate and equal universes, one where you actually write this post and one where not. In the path where you do, this results in me sitting here, writing this post or not, on my choice, creating two equal forks of the universe.

Simply spoken.

But it's all timey wimey and wibbly wobbly stuff, to quote one of the most famous time travellers ever.

Comment: so when we travel past(if we can) we don't travel to parallel universe right?

Comment: I've been in 2000BC, 2016 and 4093 and asked around about time travel. Yet, no one knows exactly if and how it works. We have to wait.

Comment: But I can prove that when we travel past we travel to parallel universe

Comment: Feel free to post your prove here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/ Because then we're talking physics, physics, physics (Ok, enough Doctor Who quotes for today)

Comment: I wanted to do that but they said this isn't an appropriate physics question

Comment: What should I do to submit the prove?

Comment: @AlexandervonWernherr There was something in the news recently about time travel and parellel universes: http://bit.ly/2glkV1m

Comment: @ThomBlairIII The "news" say "If the many worlds theory is true" which isn't proven, time travel might be possible, with out stating why. It's doubtful...

Comment: Is there any reason about how to time travel with parellel universes?

Comment: I thought this article(http://www.nature.com/news/2010/100317/full/news.2010.130.html)  prove parellel universes doesn't it?